# C# Application takes a long time to return from sleep after high uptime

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, memory, garbage-collection

I have a C# application which runs a number of threads that look like this.

```
public void Update()
{
    long UpdateInterval = 50;

    while (_running)
    {
        long start = TimeMgr.Milliseconds();

        if (start - _updateFinished > 200)
            _logger.Warn("waking up from sleep too long - took {Time} ms. Thread ID: {Thread}", (start - _updateFinished), _threadId);


        UpdateLogic();

       _updateFinished = TimeMgr.Milliseconds();

       long elapsed = _updateFinished - start;


       if (elapsed < UpdateInterval)
          Thread.Sleep((int)(UpdateInterval - elapsed));
       else
       {
           if (elapsed > 200)
              _logger.Warn("update took too long. {Time}ms. Thread ID: {Thread}", elapsed, _threadId);

       }
    }
}
```

However after 24h+ of running the "waking up from sleep too long" message starts to trigger indicating that its taking 300ms, for most threads every 5-10 seconds. I assumed it could be the garbage collector, so we switched to `gcServer = true` which then the application uses more memory, however still < 40% avaliable before this issue starts up again after ~24 hours.

Running dotTrace shows that the application is spending most of the time sleeping, which is to be expected under low load.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmXET.png

We previously had this issue running on Windows 10 using `gcServer = true` when the application creeped up to 95% of ram usage, we switched to `gcServer = false` which seems to solve the issue.

However since moving to our new machine running Windows Sever 2019 Core, this issue has seemed to have creeped up again and changing this value seems to have no effect other delaying this effect from 20% memory usage to 30% memory usage.

Our current app.config settings are set to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
    <gcConcurrent enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/></startup></configuration>
```

and we initially set this on startup of the application

```
GCSettings.LatencyMode = GCLatencyMode.SustainedLowLatency;
```

Ideally we would like garbage collection to take the least amount of time possible. The server has 64gb of memory dedicated to it that i am happy for this application to take advantage of. We normally do updates to this application 1 or 2 times a week, so ideally we would like 1 week of uptime (which we could achieve on our Windows 10 machine)

All help is appreciated

Edit: Added TimeMgr.Milliseconds() code

```
private static readonly DateTime EpochDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
public static long Milliseconds()
{
    return (long)(DateTime.UtcNow - EpochDateTime).TotalMilliseconds;
}
``
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `TimeMgr.Milliseconds();`?

Comment: Added the code to the question, this works fine for the first 24 hours.

Comment: Now I want to know what `EpochDateTime` is. ;)  Just looking for overflow...

Comment: It's the static readonly that is at the top of that code section. We also had no issues running for 7 days straight on our Windows 10 box (when we switched to gcServer = false)

Comment: OK, well it's nothing to do with overflow then.

Comment: My first recommendation would be to switch to `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to have a more precise timing. (It uses QueryPerformanceCounter internally on windows platforms and also works well on Linux distributions where .Net Core is availble) Instead of `EpochDateTime`, just start a static stopwatch (`Stopwatch chronometer = Stopwatch.StartNew();`, and in `MilliSeconds()` just return `chronometer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds`

Comment: 'I assumed it could be the garbage collector': To make sure that the GC had run during the waiting period, you can check the return values of `GC.CollectionCount()` for generations 1, 2 and 3 before going to sleep and after waking up.

Comment: I would recommend using Timeline profiling mode in dotTrace in this case. You'll see the amount of garbage collection (if the issue is caused by GC), or other useful things about UpdateLogic().